# how to insert a variable on the table arrive for vlookup

Tags: vlookup

I'm trying to insert a variable in the table arrive section for a vlookup but I'm getting an error

```
=VLOOKUP(D29,'LINEA-" & A29 & "1'!D:I,6,0)

=VLOOKUP(D29,'LINEA-1'!D:I,6,0)
```

It should be able to find values from cells on five different sheets named LINEA-1 to 5

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

**If this answer helped you, please upvote and mark as correct so i can get some reputation going to be able to comment on posts, thanks**

On your first sheet or in a new sheet, go to `Formulas > Name Manager` and add variables to the workbook.

For the sake of this explanation, i'll do everything in **Sheet1**n and i'll have one additional sheet called **LINEA-1**

1. Name Manager: add **page_name** to cell **$A$1**
2. Name Manager: add **page_num** to cell **$A$2**
3. Name Manager: add **cell** to cell **$A$3**

The values for each will be

1. LINEA-
2. 1
3. F10

The value of F10 on sheet LINEA-1 is the text **A**

To access the sheet, simply use the function call `INDIRECT`

Example: `=INDIRECT(CONCAT("'",page_name, page_num,"'!",cell))`

So for example, if i have the following table (in cells A14:B18)

```
PARTY CODE  NAME
A   DEMOCRATIC
B   REPUBLICAN
C   DECLINE TO STATE
D   INDEPENDENT
```

Then a simple VLOOKUP would be

```
=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(CONCAT("'",page_name, page_num,"'!",cell)),A14:B18,2)
```

would return **DEMOCRATIC**